# WCF json items array

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json-deserialization

Question is simple, but I can not understand how to solve this.
I am using C# WCF.
There is a simple JSON input:

```
{
    "Param1": "QWERTY",
    "Param2": "123",
    "itemsArray": [
        "First item",
        "Second item",
        "Third item"
    ], // quantity of items may be from 1 to infinity..
    "Param3": "ASDFG"
}
```

And I can not deserialize it correctly.

```
  [OperationContract]
              [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/data",
              RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
              ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
     string IncomingPost(PostData p);

[DataContract]
    public class PostData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Param1{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Param2{ get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string[] ItemsArray { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Param3 { get; set; }

    }
```

Of course, this does not work. I return JSON back to client(for test), and field where I want to see array is empty.

```
public string IncomingPost(PostData p) // JSON ECHO
        {           

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
                    new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PostData));
            MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
            ser.WriteObject(mem, p);            

            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(mem.ToArray());
            return json;

        }
```

Debug p value : ItemsArray  null    string[]

Comment: `ItemsArray` vs `itemsArray`?

Comment: Right you are!  Silly error... OMG, it seems, I need some rest. To continue subject, could you tell me, if using  a string[] is good practice? Should I use some collection type instead of an array?

Comment: I don't think it matters if you use array or list or some other collection type. If you don't have a reason to prefer one over the other then I wouldn't worry about it.